# How do I solve the following limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The solution to this limit should be 1, but I don't know how to solve it. I suspect I should rewrite the sequence but it's not geometrical or arithmetic as far as I can see.

$\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\left(1+2^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}+3^{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}+\ldots \:+x^{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)}{x}\right)$

Comment: If $a_n \to A$, then the sequence of arithmetic means $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ also converges to $A$. Prove that, and that $n^{1/n} \to 1$.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802232/rudins-principle-of-mathematical-analysis-exercise-3-14) could be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Stolz-Cesaro theorem to evaluate this limit.

Read about it here at http://planetmath.org/stolzcesarotheorem.

Now, in the context of the definition of the theorem in that link, set
$$ a_x= 1+2^{\frac{1}{2}}+3^{\frac{1}{3}}+4^{\frac{1}{4}}+ \cdots + x^{\frac{1}{x}} $$
And,
$$ b_x= x.$$

It follows that $b_x$ is positive, strictly increasing and unbounded, satisfying the requisites for the Stolz-Cesaro theorem.

Now, $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{a_{x+1}-a_x}{b_{x+1}-b_x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{ \left(1+2^{\frac{1}{2}}+3^{\frac{1}{3}}+4^{\frac{1}{4}}+ \cdots + (x+1)^{\frac{1}{x+1}}\right) - \left(1+2^{\frac{1}{2}}+3^{\frac{1}{3}}+4^{\frac{1}{4}}+ \cdots + x^{\frac{1}{x}} \right) } { (x+1)-(x)} $$

Thus, $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{a_{x+1}-a_x}{b_{x+1}-b_x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} (x+1)^{\frac{1}{x+1}} = 1.$$

(The final result can be obtained trivially by taking logarithms and using the fact that $ln(x) < x$ when $x >0$.)

Thus, by using the Stolz-Cesaro theorem, $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{a_x}{b_x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{a_{x+1}-a_x}{b_{x+1}-b_x} = \bf{1}.$$

And we are done.

Comment: Verified without upvote hahah :P